# Using Qt To Build A Full Screen Layout

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface

I am trying to use qt along with the qt designer to create a simple full screen webview with a line edit and a button above to create a really simple browser.

The problem is that the layout doesn't want to expand to fill all of the available space.  I seem to think that I am missing something really simple, but I just can't seem to figure it out.

Here is an overview of my layout

```
<MainWindow>
    <GridView>
        <VBoxLayout>
            <HBoxLayout>            
                <lineEdit /><PushButton /> 
            </HBoxLayout>
            <WebView />
        </VBoxLayout>
    </GridView>
</MainWindow>
```

Here is the code on the MainWindow Class

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
QMainWindow(parent),
ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{

    ui->setupUi(this);
    ui->lineEdit->showFullScreen();
    ui->pushButton->showFullScreen();

    ui->webView->load(QUrl("http://google.com"));

    ui->webView->showFullScreen();

 }
```

and here is the main code

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.showMaximized();
    return a.exec();
}
```

It comes out looking like this instead of the webview and lineedit filling the whole amount of space
[image]

Is there anyway of doing this in Qt, I would have assumed that this was a standard thing to want to do.

Many Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to replace the GridView by the VBoxLayout directly above.
What is the grid view you use exactly ?

```
<MainWindow>
    <VBoxLayout>
        <HBoxLayout>            
            <lineEdit /><PushButton /> 
        </HBoxLayout>
        <WebView />
    </VBoxLayout>
</MainWindow>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your Object Property "sizePolicy" is set Maximum and "maximumSize" is 16777215, then w.showFullscreen should work

Comment: thanks but I would like to know on what object..? the Main window or the webview

Answer (score 0):

If you mean that you want the window to fill the entire screen, hiding the task bar and title bar, you should replace this:

```
w.showMaximized();
```

with this:

```
w.showFullScreen();
```

If you instead mean that you want your line edit and web view widgets to fill the window that contains them, "full screen" doesn't mean what you think it does. Your problem is probably related to your layouts in designer, and we don't have enough information in your original post to properly diagnose it. Given how simple your UI is at this point, the easiest thing to do is probably break all layouts and start over.

Whatever it is that you want, you definitely shouldn't be calling `showFullScreen()` on your line edit, push button, or web view.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the problem is that you've set up the BoxLayout *inside* the parent widget, rather than setting the parent widget to use a BoxLayout.  In Qt Designer, you should be able to right-click on the parent widget and set the layout, and it will expand like you want.  If you just add a BoxLayout to a widget from the toolbar, it won't automatically expand to match its parent.

See this link for more details: http://embrisk.com/notes/qt_resize.html

Answer (score 0):

Expanding upon Stephen Bell's answer (I'd comment but I lack the reputation), as it took me awhile to figure this out as well.

If you have completely designed the layout you wish to have fullscreen, right-click on the "Main Window" in the far right of the screen. A pull-down should appear. Click Layout, then Grid Layout. Main Window should assume a grid layout. It should not change the positioning of your objects at all in Qt Designer. Yet, it should fix the fullscreen.

If MainWindow does not have a layout, your layout will likely have whitespace or deadspace without an explanation.